# How to fix Android Volley Error in StringRequest?

Tags: android, android-volley

I have API in http://202.158.68.155:7890/cobra/api/getDataByNopol

if i test in postman its work, but in android volley error null

```
final RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://202.158.68.155:7890/cobra/api/getDataByNopol", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            hideDialog();
            Log.e(TAG, "Response Detail -> "+response);
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("ERROR", error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ERROR "+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            requestQueue.stop();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();

            param.put("nopol", "L 6967 TJ");
            param.put("username", "uat2");
            param.put("token", "02E184D3C82B6DA4750A214C4");
            return param;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_json);
}
```

how to handle this case ?

Comment: _"if i test in postman its work, but in android volley error"_ What's the error? Please [edit] and post error logs here. And also post Postman screenshots.

Comment: please provide error and brief description so we can find better solution

Comment: Error Volley null

Comment: Try using JsonObjectRequest instead of StringRequest. Might help.